# Click Item to Increase Quantity in Cart - Android POS App - Java

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to modify an app. Currently when an item is clicked it gets to the cart. But this click works only one time. If clicked second time it will show error as its programmed to do so.

What I'm trying to achieve is that Multiple clicks on an item should increase the quantity of item in the cart instead of giving error.

[image]

```
package com.app.smartpos.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.app.smartpos.R;
import com.app.smartpos.database.DatabaseAccess;
import com.app.smartpos.pos.PosActivity;
import com.app.smartpos.product.EditProductActivity;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import es.dmoral.toasty.Toasty;

public class PosProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PosProductAdapter.MyViewHolder> {


    private List<HashMap<String, String>> productData;
    private Context context;
    MediaPlayer player;
    public static int count;


    public PosProductAdapter(Context context, List<HashMap<String, String>> productData) {
        this.context = context;
        this.productData = productData;
        player = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.delete_sound);

    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PosProductAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.pos_product_item, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final PosProductAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(context);

        databaseAccess.open();
        String currency = databaseAccess.getCurrency();

        final String product_id = productData.get(position).get("product_id");
        String name = productData.get(position).get("product_name");
        final String product_weight = productData.get(position).get("product_weight");
        final String product_stock = productData.get(position).get("product_stock");
        final String product_price = productData.get(position).get("product_sell_price");
        final String weight_unit_id = productData.get(position).get("product_weight_unit_id");
        String base64Image = productData.get(position).get("product_image");


        databaseAccess.open();
        final String weight_unit_name = databaseAccess.getWeightUnitName(weight_unit_id);

        holder.txtProductName.setText(name);

        //Low stock marked as RED color
        int getStock=Integer.parseInt(product_stock);
        if (getStock>5) {
            holder.txtStock.setText(context.getString(R.string.stock) + " : " + product_stock);
        }
        else
        {
            holder.txtStock.setText(context.getString(R.string.stock) + " : " + product_stock);
            holder.txtStock.setTextColor(Color.RED);

        }
        holder.txtWeight.setText(product_weight + " " + weight_unit_name);
        holder.txtPrice.setText(currency + product_price);


        holder.cardProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                if (getStock<=0)
                {

                    Toasty.warning(context, R.string.stock_is_low_please_update_stock, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {

                    Log.d("w_id", weight_unit_id);
                    databaseAccess.open();


                    int check = databaseAccess.addToCart(product_id, product_weight, weight_unit_id, product_price, 1, product_stock);

                    databaseAccess.open();
                    int count=databaseAccess.getCartItemCount();
                    if (count==0)
                    {
                        PosActivity.txtCount.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        PosActivity. txtCount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        PosActivity.txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                    }

                    if (check == 1) {
                        Toasty.success(context, R.string.product_added_to_cart, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        player.start();
                    } else if (check == 2) {

                        Toasty.info(context, R.string.product_already_added_to_cart, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } else {
                        Toasty.error(context, R.string.product_added_to_cart_failed_try_again, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                }
            }


        });


        if (base64Image != null) {
            if (base64Image.length() < 6) {
                Log.d("64base", base64Image);
                holder.product_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_placeholder);
                holder.product_image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            } else {


                byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(base64Image, Base64.DEFAULT);
                holder.product_image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length));

            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return productData.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        CardView cardProduct;
        TextView txtProductName,txtStock, txtWeight, txtPrice;

        //Button btnAddToCart;
        ImageView product_image;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            txtProductName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_product_name);
            txtWeight = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_weight);
            txtPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_price);
            txtStock = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_stock);
            product_image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_product);
            cardProduct=itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_product);

        }
    }

}
```

Currently increase or decrease quantity option is only on the cart page.

Comment: Incomplete code makes it difficult to help. Where `check` comes from? Where it is modified?

Comment: @Kozmotronik, Apologies. I have updated the code. Can you please have a look?

Comment: Well, I can see that the author is used the `count` variable to control the visibility and value of textview. But what `check` is used for I didn't get it. I can also see that product adding to the card is controlled by `check` variable. But the number which `databaseAccess.addToCart()` method returns, plays an important role. Looks like it returns a state-like numbers about the operation. Can we see the `databaseAccess.addToCart()` method implementation?

Comment: ```int check = databaseAccess.addToCart(product_id, product_weight, weight_unit_id, product_price, 1, product_stock);```

this is adding quantity 1 to the database. If I change the number 1 in above code to number 2, every item click will add 2 quantity of item in the cart. And I can not find databaseAccess.addToCart() in any other file.

Comment: I see, this is tragic. Because that method is what we need to have a look since all saving operations is done in it. The value it returns is just a state indicating value. But what you want to do is to `addToCart` and then increase the quantity everytime the same item is clicked. Unfortunately all card operations are done in the `DatabaseAccess` class. So I won't be able to help in this case since I can't see its implementation.